# How can I use output of a execi in a conky in a subsequent line

Tags: conky

I'm not a coder, just someone who is trying to work with conky for default distribution with a Linux distro. Here I am trying to get automatic net setup.

1. Following posts here and elsewhere, I am able to print the active network interface with this line:

   ${color2}ACTIVE: ${color3}${execi -300 netup}${color}

The "netup" refers to a small script in /usr/local/bin/ that has a single line:

```
ip addr show | awk '/inet.*brd/{print $NF; exit}'
```

In my case that conky line produces on the screen: **ACTIVE: interface_name** (see image below). So far, so excellent.

2. Now I would like to replace an interface-specific command about traffic or any other net info with the name that that script outputs, which would save me and the user a certain amount of hassle. I tried this, which works fine if wlan0 etc. is used:

   Down: ${downspeedf netup}kB/s ${alignr}Up: ${upspeedf netup}kB/s
   ${downspeedgraph netup 30,120 000000 000000} ${alignr}${upspeedgraph netup 30,120 000000 000000}

That clearly isn't correct, b/c the graph shows but has no content. 
[image: net graphs with no content]

Two questions: 1)  is there a way to read the active interface that was just written one line earlier?; 2) if not, how can I incorporate the output of the netup script in those down and up graphs?

Appreciate any help.

Jerry

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is call `eval` to delay the call of `upspeedf` and so on until you have called your script and it has returned the name of the interface.

For example,

```
${eval $${downspeedgraph ${exec netup} 30,120 000000 000000} } 
${alignr}
${eval $${upspeedgraph   ${exec netup} 30,120 000000 000000} }
```

Note the doubling of `$` which will become a single `$` for the eval.
Unfortunately, your script will be called on each update cycle, so you may want to optimise your script. There is no difference if you use `execi` with an interval.

For full versatility, you will need to use a lua function, which is quite a lot to learn. If your interface only needs to be determined once at the start, then why not write a small startup script to find the interface name and edit the .conkyrc file with that name before running conky.

---

Note, `${eval}` is broken in version 1.10 until this [patch](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/commit/d8cbdffe95c09392caab7b11139013d4e3fc8b31) which I think is for 1.10.3 or .4.

Comment: Lua is way out of my range, so I think I will try the startup script first. **Thanks**.