# How can I create a custom conky bar for diskio in Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, conky

I am using conky 1.10.3 (conky-all) in Ubuntu 16.10 (x86-64), kernel 4.8.0-59-generic, Cinnamon 3.0.7.

How can I create a bar for diskio (actually, one for diskio_read and another for diskio_write)?
Conky has diskio (which gives a number) and diskiograph - no bars.

I tried, but could not find a way, to use something like `${execbar $diskio}`.

I also messed a little with a lua script, namely BARGRAPH WIDGET v2.1 by wlourf, http://u-scripts.blogspot.com/2010/07/bargraph-widget.html but, although using

```
{
    name="cpu",
    --arg="%S",
    max=100,
    angle=90,
    alarm=50,
    bg_colour={0x00ff00,0.25},
    fg_colour={0x00ff00,1},
    alarm_colour={0xff0000,1},
    x=0,y=610,
    blocks=1,
    height=250,width=25,
    smooth=true,
    mid_colour={{0.5,0xffff00,1}}

}
```

works, if I put "diskio" instead of "cpu" I get an empty bar (while conky's diskiograph clearly shows disk IO).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem when using `name="diskio_read"` and `diskio_write` with the given lua bargraph widget is that these two functions return numbers like `2.33KiB` rather than simple integers like `12345`. The widget only uses the lua function `tonumber()` to convert returned values, and this fails on these strings.

The other problem is that of course you need to set `max=` to some suitable value (eg 100000000) as the disk io is not scaled to 100% like the cpu.

You can get round the first problem, if you are not using any other conky features, by resetting the global variable that requests values to be *human readable*:

```
conky.config = {
  format_human_readable = false,
  ...
```

Alternatively, you can edit the widget file, `bargraph.lua`, in function `setup_bar_graph()`, change the line:

```
value = tonumber(conky_parse(string.format('${%s %s}', t.name, t.arg)))
```

to something like

```
local result = conky_parse(string.format('${%s %s}', t.name, t.arg))
value = tonumber(result)
if value==nil then value = my_tonumber(result) end
```

and add your own tonumber function just before the function `conky_main_bars()`.

```
-- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/409006/119298
function my_tonumber(n)
  local capture = {string.match(n,"^(%d+\.?%d*)([KMGTPB])")}
  if #capture<=0 then return 0 end
  local v = tonumber(capture[1])
  if #capture==1 then return v end
  if capture[2]=="K" then return v*1024 end
  if capture[2]=="M" then return v*1024*1024 end
  if capture[2]=="G" then return v*1024*1024*1024 end
  if capture[2]=="T" then return v*1024*1024*1024*1024 end
  return v
end
```

Comment: Hello and thanks a lot for your response.  \n I figured there should be a problem with $diskio values like "20,13KiB", so I tried to use 
${exec echo $eval{$diskio} | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z ]*$//' -e 'y/,/./'}
but it outputs nothing in conky.
The same with ${exec ${eval $cpu}} - which gives "#sh: 1: Bad substitution" in the terminal. \n I'll test your advice and let you know - thanks again. \n PS\n I also tried things like $${...}, but it just outputs e.g. "$diskio". Is there anything more concise than plain "man conky"?

Comment: You might get some more examples in the [wiki](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/wiki). You can also look at an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406985/119298) to another question on conky that uses eval and $$.

Comment: Can't comment on your eval post, but:  ${exec netup}  gives "eno1",    
${downspeed eno1} gives "212B",   ${downspeed ${exec netup}} gives "0B",  ${downspeed $${exec netup}} gives "0B",  ${downspeed ${exec echo ${exec netup}}} gives "0B",  
${eval $${downspeed ${exec netup}}} gives "${downspeed eno1}",  
${exec ${eval $${downspeed ${exec netup}}}} gives(in terminal) "sh: 1: Bad substitution",  
${exec $${eval ${downspeed ${exec netup}}}} gives(in terminal) "sh: 1: Bad substitution",  
${exec ${eval $${downspeed ${exec netup}}}}gives(in terminal) "sh: 1: Bad substitution"

Comment: Maybe I'm being thick, but I cannot seem to grasp the syntax - I also cannot put a newline in the comment (Firefox/Ubuntu)!

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a bug introduced by 1.10, which was a major rewrite. It works as intended in 1.9.1. The github sources are fixed (currently version 1.10.7, but 1.10.4 may be ok too). For example, this should display the time in the window: `${eval "Local time is $${time %a, %d %b %Y %T %z}"}`

Comment: Damn!  I'll try to install the latest version and see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: I was unable to compile the latest version (ccmake complained about not finding lua!), so I downloaded the latest deb package (http://gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/conky/conky-all_1.10.6-1.1_amd64.deb). Once I installed it, ${eval $${diskio}} came out OK. However, ${eval $${diskio | sed -e 's/[a-zA-Z ]*$//' -e 'y/,/./'}} was still not working (the sed expression works in terminal). Perhaps I should go with 1.9.1? For the time being, I chose to use a second conky window, dedicated to HDD data, with format_human_readable = false, which works.

Answer (score 0):

How can i add my own variables to create a Bar ?

Like this

```
${execi 5 nvidia-smi | grep -Eo '...%.+?W' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -c1-2}
```

It shows the NumericValue of the GPU-FanSpeed without %

Comment: Thanks for the answer - and welcome here, but the question is how to create a bar, not show a number.